# Visual Basic 2010 HTTP POST Request

Tags: vb.net, http, web-scraping

How can I send a POST HTTP request to a server (in Visual Basic 2010) and then receive the reply into a string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this via HttpWebRequest.   Just set the [HttpWebRequest.Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.method.aspx) to "POST".

For details, see the example on the MSDN page for [HttpWebRequest.Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.method.aspx).  The call to [GetReponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) will return a WebReponse which includes a Stream.  You can then read the string information from the Stream using a StreamReader.