# Craigslist BulkPosting

Tags: vb.net, rss, craigslist

I'm using vb.net WinForms am Am attempting to use [Craigslist BulkPost](http://www.craigslist.org/about/bulk_posting_interface)

**Craigslist says to** https://post.craigslist.org/bulk-rss/post - Submit RSS to this URL to be posted.

**My question** is how to **read**, **edit** and **post** back to an RSS Feed. ( Does not have to be craigslist for example and i can finish the fine coding, i have never worked with RSS Feeds and cannot find any good example code or documentation on how to start.)

I have tried but sofar unsuccesfully and only partially sucessfully using `Browser` control.

Thanks in advance for any docs / advice on how to start this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Searching **how to run http post from vb.net** in google you will find to look at

- [A Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Wzel-g1U54)
- [An Asp.net Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108531/how-to-send-a-post-in-net-vb)
- [Another Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918639/visual-basic-2010-http-post-request)
- [2nd Best example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b2677bcc-565c-47fd-9da3-70f48498416c/vbnet-rss-xml-parse-node-to-winform)
- [And this example](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/145103-rss-feeds-in-vbnet/)

Please us some source code, before most of us won't to help you.